# Download image (I have the link) from the front-end as user?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, google-cloud-storage

I want to allow my user to download a image, i know that if i have a file i can use the tag download and it will work, but it doesn't work if i have the link

I have already tried the download tag, and read the google cloud storage downloading-objects docs but the problem with the last one is that it gets downloaded on my server, also i tried to return the file but it is just a promise with no file info

Front-end with the download code (doesn't work), i have tried it with `download={preview}`

```
      <div className={classes.fileInputs}>
        <a download href={preview} title="Imagen">
          <img
            src={preview}
            alt='Preview obj'
            className={classes.imgPreview}
          />
        </a>
```

This is how i thought it should work but it didn't, download triggers a request to the back-end but the image is downloaded in my server

```
<Button color="inherit" onClick={() => download()}>
   Download
</Button>
```

I just want that a click in the button download will make the client have its image

Comment: I understand that by following the Google Cloud Storage documentation, the requested file is successfully downloaded on the server-side, but isn’t properly sent client-side. Are you using NodeJS as your server-side language? If not, what other language stack are you using? Furthermore, can you provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how your “download()” function is implemented client-side - as well as how your server-side code handles the incoming request to fetch the file from Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can use axios:

```
axios({
url: 'http://localhost:5000/static/example.jpg',
method: 'GET',
responseType: 'blob', // important
}).then((response) => {
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.jpg');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
});
```

You can check it in more details [here](https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743)

Answer (score 0):

To set type of file and filename from "content-disposition" -header you can use this:

const blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.data.type});

const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

const link = document.createElement('a');

link.href = url;

const contentDisposition = response.headers['content-disposition'];

let fileName = 'unknown';

if (contentDisposition) {

```
const fileNameMatch = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/);

if (fileNameMatch.length === 2)

    fileName = fileNameMatch[1];
```

}

link.setAttribute('download', fileName);

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

link.remove();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);